# Is it possible to get autocomplete list to scroll?

Tags: material-ui

Using material-ui autocomplete to select from about 600 items.

Is it possible to get autocomplete to offer a scrollable list of options?

Answer (score 25, accepted):

You can modify the CSS of the list using listStyle...

```
<AutoComplete
  listStyle={{ maxHeight: 200, overflow: 'auto' }}
...
/>
```

In the newest version of materiel ui (v4.9.11) it is possible as:

```
<AutoComplete
  ListboxProps={{ style: { maxHeight: 200, overflow: 'auto' } }}
...
/>
```

Comment: This doesn't seem to work in v4.11.0

Comment: How does one apply the same properties to the actual selected values of the autocomplete? To continue on @HenrikBechmann's question, what if the user selected all 600 items? How could one apply the same formatting to that input box so that it shows a scrollable list of selected values?

Answer (score 0):

I have simply used "sx" for scrollable list of options in Autocomplete.

```
<Autocomplete
  sx={{ maxHeight: 200, overflow: 'auto' }}
...
/>
```